# Can we use the output of a perlin noise (feTurbulence) to hue rotate background color?

Tags: svg

Context: I have build a program that make the following effect and I would like to add the effect in the SVG export but I have not found a way to do this effect in SVG it at the moment.

[image: Hue Perlin Noise]

The effects in the inners circles are just a hue rotate based on the output a perlin noise channel applied to the color in background. Is it possible to do this in SVG ? May be is there a way to use "feColorMatrix" with values that depends on an input ?

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to be a genius or an enthusiastic math oriented programming propellerhead, you propably can understand Inkscape's filters and build there what you need:

[image]

This stuff is far beyond my capablities. It is a fully random edit of an effect that adds noise to a shape. Some mouse clicks caused feTurbulence text to pop up - that obviously is a SVG effect primitive, one of those standard building blocks that are implemented also in Inkscape.

There's also available a couple of other blocks that can have some value to solve  your problem: "feColor matrix" and "feComposite". I do not understand them well enough to give any receipes. My guessing is based on the following screenshot:

[image]

It's taken from http://archive.flossmanuals.net/inkscape/ch049_introduction

Altough Inkscape can include to SVG code quite rich details, other software with high probablity simply reject them. I tried to open the random shape of my first screenshot in Affinity Design. It opened exactly as it was before applying my randomized filter.

Comment: The problem is that the "feColorMatrix" use fixed coefficient in its "values" property. It's fine to apply a global constant hue rotation but I don't see how to apply a hue rotation based on feTurbulence output.

The answer is maybe that it's no doable in svg currently.

Comment: @Rexxar GDSE users more paint, draw and design layouts than think matrices. Of course some of us also understand software underhood things. And definitely  some of us are also professional programmers. Unfortunately they have been busy, I guess. Programming specialists probably know your waters better. Sorry for wasting your time with elementaries.

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer :-) Maybe this question would be better on stackoverfow. Some questions are at the limit between domains.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely looking for a "multiply" effect using `<feBlend>` - see [the Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feBlend) for more.

Alternatively, you could likely do the same thing in modern web browsers [with just CSS](https://css-tricks.com/basics-css-blend-modes/#article-header-id-0).